# Java/Android Asynchronous work in the background

Tags: java, android, wcf, android-asynctask, development-environment

in the past few days I have been trying to figure something but had no luck, I am developing an android game, I have 3 packages for now each with its own purpose:

1 - package for GUI classes.
2 - package that has classes communicates with my wcf service (login/pass DB)
3 - package that holds my asynchronous classes/workers (like a bridge between GUI and SERVICE)

I am not sure if this is even the right approach when it comes to android/java game development, but what I want to achieve is a simple registeration/login in the GUI and when the user is done registering or logining, while the gui talks to the service through the "bridge", a message is displayed for the user like a dialog saying "registering" or "loging in".

Now I would like to hear tips/feedback from more experienced programmers, on how to acomplish this, and if this is the right aproach, and most importantly some examples for this specific case would be really helpfull, I tried to work with the asynctask but I couldn't figure out how to communicate between these 3 seperate packages and return the result from the service back to the gui through the async task.

Comment: How do you create your GUI? Is it realized through widgets and layouts? You use OpenGL or Canvas? In the first case just look at some examples how the AsyncTask is used. For other cases you need to be a little bit more into multithreading and concurent programming to fully understand the process.

Comment: The entire gui stuff is widgests/layouts/xml, thats the easy part, I cant figure out how to send the parameters from the gui through the asyncTask to the service and back with a response, and I am not even sure if AsyncTask is the best aproach here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

```
public class FindEventsActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pd;

// lots of other code up here
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clickete);

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("loading");

    findViewById(R.id.clickLayout).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new LongOperation().execute("");
                    pd.show();
                }
            });
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulates your intensive work
                // Update your progress if you want
                this.publishProgress();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Handle fail or success accordingly
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // Update UI according to your progress
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: This is actually, a helpfull example, but as I mention above, I am using my async task in a different package, I dont want it to be a subclass of the GUI, I want the gui and async seperated and clean, Any ideas on how this example can be used in the way I need it? pass the result between packages (seperated classes)

Comment: Where ever do you create your asynctask this should be the result you are getting. If you have problems setting your progress dialog to show outside of your GUI class, just wrap it in runOnUITHread

Comment: The thing is.. lets say I want the async class to give the result to the register method that is located on the GUI class, so the GUI class knows how to handle the situation for example if the register succeeded or failed, So I am not sure how to make the seperated async task class pass the result to the gui all the way from the service class where the result is coming from.

Comment: Then handlers are the way to go and there are a lot of examples out there. If you still have issues feel free to poke me again.

Comment: Thank you marko, Can you just clear out one thing for me, when you say handlers you mean not go the "Async task" way? or use it and handlers?